# Return from method with Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, return

Sorry for the confusing title, I'm not sure how to describe it in minimal words but basically what I'm trying to do is return a LinkedList from a method. But I wanna put the actual content inside the method inside a Thread, and then return the data when the thread is done. Here is the code I am using:

```
public static LinkedList<Result> get(final String prefix){
    final LinkedList<Result> results = new LinkedList<Result>();
    if(thread != null){
        thread.stop();
        thread = null;
    }
    thread = new Thread(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try{
                        URL url = new URL(String.format(URL_INFO, prefix));
                        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                        connection.setReadTimeout(Timeout.TIMEOUT);
                        connection.setConnectTimeout(Timeout.TIMEOUT);
                        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                        Scanner reader = new Scanner(is);
                        while(reader.hasNextLine()){
                            String line = reader.nextLine();
                            if(line != null){
                                if(line.contains(String.format(WORDS_INFO, prefix))){
                                    String[] s = line.split(String.format(PREFIX_INFO, prefix));
                                    String[] s2 = s[1].split("\">");
                                    if(s2.length > 0){
                                        for(int i = 1; i < s2.length; i++){
                                            String l = s2[i];
                                            String[] split = l.split(FINAL_SPLIT);
                                            results.add(new Result(prefix, split[0].trim()));
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        reader.close();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
    );
    thread.start();
    return results;
}
```

The thread is statically defined inside the variables section. And basically the problem here is that it returns an empty LinkedList because it's not waiting for the Thread to be finished. How can I wait until the Thread is finished before returning the LinkedList? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

NOTE: The issue is not anything to do with reading the URL, the problem is is that it's returning an empty LinkedList because the Thread has not finished yet and I want to know how to wait until the Thread is done before it returns something.

Comment: why are you putting it in a separate thread if you want to wait for it to return?

Comment: The whole point of threads is to do things in parallel.  There's no point starting a second thread if the first one is just going to wait for the second one to finish.  Might as well just do the work on the first thread.

Comment: [`Thread.stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29) is deprecated. See [Why are Thread.stop, Thread.suspend and Thread.resume Deprecated?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: @Wyzard I'm aware of that and the reason why this isn't possible is because this is for Android Development, you can't modify a View within a Thread.

Comment: All Java code runs within a thread.  There's a certain thread (called the UI thread) that's the only one allowed to interact with views, but your example code doesn't do anything with views, so it's not clear how that rule is related to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait till the thread completes execution. Look up the documentation on [`Thread.join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29).

This is just one way to do what you are trying. There are many others, such as [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Comment: Alright I've looked up an example online and it seems like you call Thread.join immediately after you start your thread. So after I started the thread, I added in a Thread.join on the line underneath.

Edit: So it worked but it still seems kind of slow. I was kind of expecting no lag when I were to call this method because I basically call this method each time the user enters something different inside the textbox.

Comment: But this could also be due to the fact that this is actually for Android Development, so I'm a little unsure if it's because of the lack of RAM my emulator has, but thank you.

Comment: You can be also interested in [Callable / Future](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/get_netbeans_6)

Comment: @Pshemo : That's actually so weird because right before I asked this question, I tried to search it so I don't seem too needy, and I actually went to this page and got really confused. But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using a thread here at all. If you have to fork the thread and then wait for it to finish, then you should just execute the `run()` code directly in the parent thread.

It is also important to realize that when you do something like:

```
final LinkedList<Result> results = new LinkedList<Result>();
thread = new Thread(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                ...
                results.add(new Result(prefix, split[0].trim()));
...
return results;
```

You are using the `results` object in a non-thread-safe manner.  `results` is not a synchronized collection so you would need to synchronize on it both in the `Runnable` and in the outer thread if you actually wanted to return it while the thread was still running.  Otherwise two threads are accessing the object without memory synchronization.  Since you may now be calling `join()` on the thread *before* returning, this would be a non issue since `join()` will synchronize for you.  But it is important to realize the ramifications there.

Lastly, `thread.stop()` is deprecated.  The right way to interrupt a thread is to call `thread.interrupt()` which sets the interrupt flag on the thread and causes `Thread.sleep()`, `wait()`, and some other methods to throw `InterruptedException`.